# Get the text inside "<" and ">" with grep in batch

Tags: git, batch-file

I'm trying to grep a word in a file.txt inside "<" and ">" for two days but impossible to get it. For example, i've something like that in a file.txt :

`30993250 (<someone@mail.com> 2014-09-22 12:41:56 +0200 365)`

It come from a `git blame -L 365,+1 path\to\file.cpp-e` and i want to only recover the email inside. I'm trying this following code :

`grep -oP '(?<=\<)\w+(?= \>)' ..\log\file.txt > ..\log\result.txt`

**and**

`grep -Po '(?<=\().*(?=\))' ..\log\file.txt > ..\log\result.txt`

But it doesn't works and says the syntax of file is incorrect or the specified path was not found. I don't understand, I've tried lots of combinations but nothings works...

I want to say i'm using batch under Windows. Is there somebody who can help me please ?

**EDIT :** I found a solution where i use the ASCII table like that :

`grep -oP '["\074].*["\076]' ..\log\file.txt > ..\log\result.txt`

But display the "<>" characters like this :

`<someone@mail.com>`

How i can remove that ?

Thanks

Comment: This one comes pretty close `grep -o '<[^>]\+'`. Do you have awk available?, then you can use `awk -F'[><]' '{print $2}'`

Comment: Using sed: `sed  's/^[^<]\+<\([^>]\+\).*$/\1/'`

Comment: @FredrikPihl Thanks for answer. I've try awk (gawk for me on windows...) and sed but it never works :( I edit my post because i found a beginning of solution.

Comment: @FredrikPihl  Maybe you can help me to remove this "<>" ?

Comment: Have you tried working with the `--porcelain` output? `git blame -p -L 365,+1 path\to\file.cpp-e`.

Comment: You should use `"` quotes, not just `'` to avoid problems with `<>&|` characters

Comment: @Zeeker I've try it but i have the same problem to recover the email, it stand in "<>" character. Or maybe there is a way to just output email, but i've not found.

Comment: @jeb Thanks for the tips, i remember that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep will find and show *lines*, it will not remove anything from a line.

But in your case you can read the result and remove the `<>` characters.

```
grep -oP '["\074].*["\076]' ..\log\file.txt > ..\log\result.txt
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p line=   < ..\log\result.txt
set "line=!line:<=!"
set "line=!line:>=!"
echo !line!
```

Comment: The grep `-o` option prints only the matching content, not the whole line

Comment: Ok, with thats syntax, it's working too : `gawk -F"[><]" '{print $2}' ..\log\file.txt > ..\log\result.txt` so i keep this one, with the `"` to avoid problem with special characters. Thanks everyone.

Comment: And `grep -P` supports look-behind. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28430767/1012053)

Answer (score 1):

The perl mode `-P` allows look behind. Note - I'm using GNU grep for Windows.

```
grep -P -o "(?<=<)[^>]+(?=>)" ..\log\file.txt >..\log\result.txt
```

For Windows batch users that don't have access to grep (some companies disallow 3rd party exe programs), you could use my [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) - a pure script regex search/replace utility that runs natively on Windows.

```
jrepl "<([^>]+)>" $1 /jmatch /f ..\log\file.txt /o ..\log\result.txt
```